# Remove white line in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Not really sure about what to do here. The first time i used a background image to `Cover` the background or body. Just to let you know, i have this in my css:

```
body, html
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("../images/bk.png") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    font-family: arial;
    border:0;
}
```

for some reason, when the website is maximized on my 1920x1080 monitor, it is perfect, but still has the white line on top; However, i do believe that is because of my bookmarks bar. But the line on the left is what i need to get rid of. On my second screen, which is smaller, it looks perfect, unless i maximize it. Then that line re-appears. What is this and how do i get rid of it?

Note: You can barley see it, but if you look towards the bottom, and look up, you will see the line. Here is a BETTER VIEW: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C963f.png

Also, i am pretty sure that it is not a border. I added `border:0;` in the CSS, with no luck.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a `border-left` to me..

Comment: `border: 0;` might fix it up

Comment: Well, it does, but it is not. I had to paste the image on a black background for you to see it. @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan

Comment: @MarcB Did not work. The line is still there.

Comment: Have you tried toe set the background-color to black? Maybe your bg image is just a bit smaller than your screen.

Comment: @MichielReyers Perfect. Thanks. Please add an answer. Also, why is there a `"margin"` anyway? Should my image not cover the entire background?

Comment: I think your bg image is just a bit smaller than your screen, hit ctrl - (zoom out) to see what happens when your screen would be even bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the background size is set to `cover`, and the image resolution doesn't perfectly match the aspect ratio of the browser viewport, the background fails to cover the entire element, and leaves the empty area behind. The only possible solution to this if you want to stick with `cover` is to set the `background-color` to `black` or `#000`, this will make this unnoticeable.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks and also, i appreciate the reasoning behind your answer. Explaining it made it more clear why i should use the background color.

Comment: @EliteGamer I'm glad I could help! I've faced this issue many times myself, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your bg image is just a bit smaller than your screen, hit ctrl - (zoom out) to see what happens when your screen would be even bigger. –

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually an issue with Chrome. I see that white line on every page, incluing the "new tab" screen. I'm looking for a way to get rid of it.